# SSRS data driven subscriptions for valid email addresses

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2014, ssrs-subscription

We have a tons of daily data driven subscriptions. Sometimes these subscriptions delivery fail due to even a single invalid email address (terminated employee). My question is there any way to create a parameter/code/expression that let's subscriptions to be distributed to users by skipping invalid email addresses?

Comment: Do you have a table that contains the employee status and email address? If so, you could make the distribution list based on a query via your data driven subscription.

Comment: That's interesting, what version of SSRS? In 2016 it delivers to all addresses and will report the amount that it failed/succeeded.

Comment: we are using SQL Server 2014

Comment: technically all employees email address and status info is stored  in Active Directory but I don't think we have that backed up anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment response I believe I have a solution. You will need to add some error checking in your where clause to filter out anybody with erroneous or NULL emails. Alternatively, you could have a case statement that tries to detect and correct bad emails and replace NULLS with a junk local email address.

SSRS won't fail if it can't deliver the email but apparently it will fail if you don't have an email in your dataset for data driven subscription. It's going to be up to you to make sure this doesn't happen!